# $filter not working for property Identities

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

[image: ScreenShots]
I'm trying to Use $filter on identities property but it seems not working. Though the response code is 200 I'm not getting any values. I have cross checked that the value I'm passing in query is present in the data.

I tried running the query from MS Graph API website as well but there also the same response attached the screenshot of the same

Answer (score 0):

I think that issuer should not include user name

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName,id&$filter=identities/any(c:c/issuer eq 'M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com')
```

Resource:

[Object identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/objectidentity?view=graph-rest-1.0#:%7E:text=Description-,issuer,-string)